# Creating a folder, writing a file to a shared folder on a server

Tags: .net, security

My windows service is creating a directory on a shared folder, and I am getting a error:

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path,DirectorySecurity dirSecurity)
at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path, DirectorySecurity directorySecurity)
at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)     at
```

I referencing the shared folder like: `\\255.255.255.255\myfolder.uploads\`

Any ideas on what I have to do to be able to write to this folder?  The share has Everyone and fullcontrol setup on it.

**Updates**

Do I have to impersonate a user on the other server somehow?

Comment: Under which account the service is running?

Comment: local system account, which is network service account I think.

Comment: Just as a reference note, there is no impersonation for Services/Winforms apps, that only applies to web apps (as I learned in another question 8^D)

Answer (score 1):

This could be a couple of things depending upon the platform your server runs. As a complete (and assuming a windows based server) guess cross check both the share AND the folder have write permissions given to the appropriate user account.

Just providing permissions on the share only may not work.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

For security in shared folders on .net you need to configure the .net security with [".net Framework Configuration Tool"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try running the service under your user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should explicitly run the service with the NetworkService Account:
[MSDN on NetworkService Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684272(VS.85).aspx)
It is different from the LocalSystem account you are using:
[MSDN on LocalSystem Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190(VS.85).aspx)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

in C# Im using the following :

```
string DIR_CONTA = "\\\\192.168.0.X\\folder\\subfolder";
```

you must also review shared folders options, and Security tabs